# Python Pandas DataFrames Sorting, Summing and Fetching Max Data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have just started learning Python, Pandas and NumPy and I want to find out what is the cleanest and most efficient way to solve the following problem.

I have data which holds CarManufacturer, Car, TotalCarSales, bearing in mind that the data is not small:

CarManufacturer Car TotalCarSales

Volkswagen Polo 100

Volkswagen Golf 50

Honda Jazz 40

Honda Civic 100

Question:
Which manufacturer sold the most cars according to it's top 3 best sellers?

I'm struggling to solve this efficiently. I want to avoid iterating over the data.

My thoughts:
- Load Data into DataFrame
- Index data according to CarManufacturer, Car, TotalCarSales
- Do I want to do a sort here? That would be slow? 
- Create a new DataFrame which has CarManufacturer, TotalSales. For each CarManufacturer I would need to get the top 3 TotalCarSales and take their sum - Is there a way of doing this without iterating over all records in DataFrame? What is best way to fetch the top 3? 
- Then if I sort the TotalSales and take the top 3, wouldn't the sort be slow? Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I think need:

```
print (df)
   CarManufacturer      Car  TotalCarSales
0       Volkswagen     Polo            100
1       Volkswagen   Sharan            100
2       Volkswagen     Golf             50
3           Toyota    Auris            200
4           Toyota     Aygo             10
5           Toyota  Avensis             50
6            Honda    Civic             40
7            Honda     Jazz             40
8            Honda    Civic            100
9             Seat   Toledo            200
10            Seat     Leon            400

a = (df.sort_values('TotalCarSales', ascending=False)
      .groupby('CarManufacturer')['TotalCarSales']
      .apply(lambda x: x.head(2).sum())  #for top3 change 2 to 3
      .nlargest(3).index.tolist())
print (a)
['Seat', 'Toyota', 'Volkswagen']
```

Explanation:

1. First sort `DataFrame` by column `TotalCarSales` with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)
2. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and sum first 3 top values selected by [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)
3. For 3 top `CarManufacturer` add [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and exctract values of `index`

**Details**:

```
print (df.sort_values('TotalCarSales', ascending=False))
   CarManufacturer      Car  TotalCarSales
10            Seat     Leon            400
3           Toyota    Auris            200
9             Seat   Toledo            200
0       Volkswagen     Polo            100
1       Volkswagen   Sharan            100
8            Honda    Civic            100
2       Volkswagen     Golf             50
5           Toyota  Avensis             50
6            Honda    Civic             40
7            Honda     Jazz             40
4           Toyota     Aygo             10

print (df.sort_values('TotalCarSales', ascending=False)
      .groupby('CarManufacturer')['TotalCarSales']
      .apply(lambda x: x.head(2).sum()))
CarManufacturer
Honda         140
Seat          600
Toyota        250
Volkswagen    200
Name: TotalCarSales, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do when you are learning is to try it.

It's very unlikely your data will be too large (there aren't millions of car models), but in any case, you can use `df.head(N)` to take the top N rows to try your method and see if it's slow.

Other useful functions include `df.groupby`, `df.nlargest`, `df.sort_values`

Answer (score 0):

> Do I want to do a sort here? That would be slow?

Yes, sorting within each group is a good way to get what you want. Moreover sorting is a O(nlogn) operation so it shouldn't be too slow.

> Is there a way of doing this without iterating over all records in DataFrame? What is best way to fetch the top 3?

Yes, you can use [GroupBy.head](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html). An alternative that may save you some time is [SeriesGroupBy.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) which gives you the `n` largest elements of a series, so that you won't need to sort first.